# Combining consecutive when statements?

Tags: kotlin

Given an

```
enum class As(val value: String) {
    A1("a1"),
    A2("a2"),
    A3("a3"),
}
```

I would like to set two variables, depending from an `As` object:

```
val enumAs = As.A1

val color = when(enumAs){
    A1 -> Color.White
    else -> Color.Black
}

val padding = when(enumAs){
    A1 -> 8.dp
    A2 -> 12.dp
    else -> 16.dp
}
```

As you can see, to set `color` and `padding` I have to `when` twice `enumAs`..

I bet Kotlin has a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could use a tuple (Pair) and destructuring declaration:

```
val (color, padding) = when(enumAs){
    A1 -> Color.White to 8.dp
    A2 -> Color.Black to 12.dp
    else -> Color.Black to 16.dp
}
```

But you may find it cleaner to define properties in your enum class that can define some of these values or keys for looking them up as resources so you don't need a when statement. I've never actually used the above strategy. The opportunity has never presented itself because if you have a group of different characteristics for each enum value, they often will more naturally fit in the enum class itself. If you're theming the enum values, you might define the complete styling of each in a single place and use a property of the enum as a key for matching to one of complete styles.